# Scala how to split all items in an array to another immutable array

Tags: scala

I have an input string

```
val x = "snapshot_year_month=201610,snapshot_day=05,source='zzz'"
val y = x.split(",")
```

This produces a 3 part array `y`.  Now, I want to take each item in `y` and split it again by `=` and have the final output in `Array[Array[String]`.  How would I do this?  I tried the following but it did not work.

```
var finalSplit = y.foreach(z => z.split("="))
```

Comment: Variable size. @YuvalItzchakov  I know I could create a mutable array, append to it over each iteration, but this seems like a poor approach.

Comment: `.foreach` returns a `Unit`. It doesn't return anything (at least, it doesn't return anything you can later manipulate). Use `.map` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.map` instead of `.foreach`. The latter returns `Unit`, which is meant to execute a side effect and not return any value:

```
val data = "snapshot_year_month=201610,snapshot_day=05,source='zzz'"
val splitData = x.split(",")

val finalRes: Array[Array[String]] = splitData.map(_.split("="))
```